# ImageMagick montage html coordinates incorrect when larger image is added

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-montage

I have a directory of images that I want to create a montage from.

These images have the following sizes:

- `image-00.png` = `19 x 21`
- `image-01.png` = `20 x 22`
- `image-02.png` = `25 x 30`

When I create a montage with:

```bash
magick montage *.png -mode Concatenate -background transparent info.html
```

using just the first two images, the html `coords` look correct:

```html
<map id="image" name="image">
  <area href="image-00.png" shape="rect" coords="0,0,19,21" alt="" />
  <area href="image-01.png" shape="rect" coords="20,0,39,21" alt="" />
</map>
```

However, when I add in the third image, the coordinates are different and incorrect as the first two frames are now larger:

```html
<map id="image" name="image">
  <area href="image-00.png" shape="rect" coords="0,0,24,29" alt="" />
  <area href="image-01.png" shape="rect" coords="25,0,49,29" alt="" />
  <area href="image-02.png" shape="rect" coords="50,0,74,29" alt="" />
</map>
```

I'm not sure why this happens since the dimensions of the first two frames didn't change. I'd like to be able to grab the exact position of each image from the html but I'm not sure how to do so when the coordinates aren't correct.

**Edit:**

The images I'm using:

[image: image-00.png]
[image: image-01.png]
[image: image-02.png]

Comment: Maybe the input PNGs have virtual pages associated with them. Try `magick montage  *.png +repage ...`

Comment: @MarkSetchell That doesn't seem to make a difference but from further testing if I process them individually `image-00.png image-01.png image-02.png image-03.png`, instead of using the `*.png` pattern, the coordinates appear correct.

Comment: The wild card * should be taking the images in alphanumeric order or whatever order your OS directory lists them. How are they listed in your directory? Also I note that your top left corner image's map coordinates include the gap below the top left corner image. So it ends at the top of the bottom left image.

Comment: @fmw42 Sorry it seems I was chasing the wrong issue earlier. I've narrowed down my issue to an image causing the coordinates to change.

Comment: What format?  Add +repage to remove virtual canvas issues. You may have to do that before montage (pipe your images from magick into magick montage). Montage may not recognize +repage.

Comment: Just to elucidate, Fred's suggestion means `magick *.png +repage miff:- | magick montage miff:- -mode concatenate output.html`

Comment: @fmw42 Fred, I actually ran `magick montage` with the `+repage` that I suggested in the very first comment and it didn't balk at that. Do you think it would just ignore it if it didn't recognize it? I rather hope it would say.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've tried the command you listed but the output html has the same coordinates unfortunately, just with different names for the files. I'm going to attach the images to the question if you want to validate the same results.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the images being used.